# result storing with nested (double) loop

Tags: r

I have double loop (it will be triple loop at very end but one thing at the time). I need to save its results into data frame. I have no trouble with doing it for single loop but I have problems  when I need to make nested loop. I manage to write replicable code:

```
#first i create sample df with 3 random variables and index
df=data.frame("var1"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),`
              "var2"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
              "var3"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
              "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),6)),
              "index1"=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,9)))



#lists for subseting data in loops
list.1=list(1,2)
list.2=list("A","B","C")
#first loop based on list.2
for (i in 1:length(list.2)){
  i2=list.2[i]#indicator for inside loop to subset based on letter
  for (i in 1:length(list.1)){
        x=subset(df,df$index1 %in% list.1[i] & df$index2 %in% i2 )#subseting data 
        x=subset(x,select=c("var1","var2"))#second subset is not needed for example but it exists in my loop
        MyCalcs=data.frame(
          "INDEX1"=list.1[i],
          "CALC1"=mean(x$var1+x$var2),
          "CALC2"=mean(x$var1-x$var2),
          "CALC3"=mean(x$var1*x$var2)
        )#here I make some simple calculation 
        print(MyCalcs)#this i want put into data.frame
    }
}
```

For single loop using `do.call(rbind,list)` works well, but in this case result was last 2 rows of `print(MyCalcs)`. I also tried with `assign` but with no success.

Comment: Can you show the desired output based on your data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this by initializing the dataset and adding rows to it. This avoids the use of rbind. My approach is prone to errors in indexing, so I changed the indexing variable of your second loop to a different variable than the indexing variable in your first loop.

```
#first i create sample df with 3 random variables and index 
df=data.frame("var1"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
          "var2"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
          "var3"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
          "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),6)),
          "index1"=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,9)))

 #lists for subseting data in loops
list.1=list(1,2)
list.2=list("A","B","C")
#here I initialize the dataset
MyCalcs.tot <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, length(list.1)*length(list.2)*4), ncol = 4))
names(MyCalcs.tot) <- c("INDEX1","CALC1", "CALC2", "CALC3")

#first loop based on list.2
for (i in 1:length(list.2)){
  i2=list.2[i]#indicator for inside loop to subset based on letter
  #your second loop used the same index as the first, 
  #this migth lead to confusion, thus i changed it to a j
  for (j in 1:length(list.1)){
    x=subset(df,df$index1 %in% list.1[j] & df$index2 %in% i2 )#subseting data 
    x=subset(x,select=c("var1","var2"))#second subset is not needed for example but it exists in my loop

    MyCalcs=data.frame(
      "INDEX1"=list.1[j],
      "CALC1"=mean(x$var1+x$var2),
      "CALC2"=mean(x$var1-x$var2),
      "CALC3"=mean(x$var1*x$var2)
    )#here I make some simple calculation 
    MyCalcs.tot[(i - 1)*length(list.1) + j,] <- MyCalcs #adding your calculations to the next row. 
    print(MyCalcs)#this i want put into data.frame
  }}
```

MyCalcs.tot is the required data frame

You could also avoid using loops altogether and use apply function:

```
#first i create sample df with 3 random variables and index 
df=data.frame("var1"=runif(48,min=0,max=1),
              "var2"=runif(48,min=0,max=1),
              "var3"=runif(48,min=0,max=1),
              "index3"=c(rep(c("do","re","mi","fa"),12)),
              "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),16)),
              "index1"=c(rep(1,24),rep(2,24)))

comb <- as.data.frame(cbind(unlist(lapply(list.1,function(x)rep(x,length(list.2)*length(list.3)))),
              rep(unlist(lapply(list.2,function(x)rep(x,length(list.3)))),length(list.1)),
              rep(unlist(list.3),length(list.1)*length(list.2))))
names(comb) <- c("INDEX1","INDEX2","INDEX3")
comb$CALC1 <- apply(comb,1,function(x)mean(apply(df[,1:2],1,function(y)y[1]+ y[2])[which(df$index1 == x[1] & df$index2 == x[2] & df$index3 == x[3])]))
comb$CALC2 <- apply(comb,1,function(x)mean(apply(df[,1:2],1,function(y)y[1]- y[2])[which(df$index1 == x[1] & df$index2 == x[2] & df$index3 == x[3])]))
comb$CALC3 <- apply(comb,1,function(x)mean(apply(df[,1:2],1,function(y)y[1]* y[2])[which(df$index1 == x[1] & df$index2 == x[2] & df$index3 == x[3])]))
```

Comment: It worked swell, however i have some troubles with this code when i tried adapt it to my more complex version of code. Luckily its easy to reproduce on my example - so lets say i want to add new column to `MyCalcs`, let it be `list.2` and `list.2=c("A","B","C")` so i adjusted:
`MyCalcs.tot <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, length(list.1)*length(list.2)*5), ncol = 5))` and `names(MyCalcs.tot) <- c("INDEX1","INDEX2","CALC1", "CALC2", "CALC3")`(replace it in your code)

Comment: and add in `MyCalcs` data frame another column:
`"INDEX2"=list.2[j]` (add it just in line under `INDEX1=list.1[i]`). What happens is `MyCalcs.tot` the column "INDEX2" should consist values `"A","B","C", but instead of that they are all ones.

Comment: sorry for splitting

Comment: Shouldn't your index for list 2 be "INDEX2"=list.2[i]?

Comment: The problem was caused by the row names, replacing MyCalcs for  `MyCalcs=c(
      list.1[j],
      list.2[i],
      mean(x$var1+x$var2),
      mean(x$var1-x$var2),
      mean(x$var1*x$var2)
    )`  solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works well with my code, however the last part is make 3rd loop (fortunately 3rd one is top of my "loop pyramid"). So I create new data frame to fill like this:
`MyCalcs.all <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, length(l.list.1)*length(list.2)*length(list.3)*4), ncol = 4))`
And analogically to your idea I tried to create data frame like this to put my result:
`MyCalcs.alll[((i - 1)*length(list.1) + j)*length(list.3),]=MyCalcs`
However i can not make it works correctly, it returns same results like in my 2 loop version. Could you explain me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I do not entirely understand what you are trying to do. Is the idea to get the results for all possible combinations of levels in list 1,2 and 3? Are you using nested loops again?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use nested loop again based on 3rd list (with df names like `list(df1,df2,df3)`) and store results. I tried to adjust your method of creating empty data frame and filling it with loop result. Is there any simple way to do it? If this requires lot of reworking or changing entire approach I can work with 2-nested loop.

Comment: I added another option using the apply function.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your effort, I am still not sure which of those two approaches I will use for my code but this have nice educational value for me.